# Метки Участники Как сделать так, чтобы в файле в который копируем были пробелы между вводимыми словами?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    File file = new File("1.txt");
  InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);  

    FileWriter fileReader = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileReader); 

    String line;

    while(!(line = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("exit")) {
        if (!line.equals(null)) {
            line.replace("", " ");
        bufferedWriter.write(line);
        }
    }

    bufferedReader.close(); 
    bufferedWriter.close();
 }  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Comment: кинь код, а не скриншот

Comment: Стектрейс можно?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать так, чтобы в файле в который копируем были пробелы между вводимыми словами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917992/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий!! 
Просто замените строку `System.out.println("Input exception");` 
на строку `exception.printStackTrace();`

Вы увидите сообщение

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

которая говорит о том, что file.txt не существует

структура должна быть такая (file.txt лежит в одной папке с папкой src)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после выполнения кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так я же создаю file.txt в папке src

Comment: файл должен быть не в src, а в одной папке с src !!

Comment: Всё, спасибо, помогло. Ещё 1 вопрос: А как сделать так, чтобы у меня не было пустых строк. Тип, чтобы в процессе копирование их удалить?

Comment: добавь ифчик в цикле. пугугли с каким условием

Comment: и отметь плиз ответ, как правильный

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try(FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt")) {
        File directory = new File("src/test");
        if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdir();

     try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/test/file.txt")){
             byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
             int length;

             while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1){
                 outputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        } 
         catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Output exception");
        }
            }
             catch (IOException exception){
             System.out.println("Input exception");
   } 
}
```

}